# Set Nvidia digital vibrance to 100 with a batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, nvidia-graphics-card

Is this possible? I'd be so stoked if I got this working. There's this game I play where I like to play it with Digital Vibrance set to 100%.

But I hate having to open NVIDIA control panel every time I wanna play, and then after I'm done open it again and set it to default (50%). I'm using a old GeForce 8600 GT card.

I've tried making a batch file with this content:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe C:\windows\system32\nvcpl.dll,dtcfg setdvc all 100
```

But it wont set it to 100.

According to [link](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf) it should work.

Example:

```
rundll32.exe NvCpl.dll,dtcfg setdvc all 16
Sets the digital vibrance on all of the displays supporting DVC to 20. On an 
adaptor that supports only DVC1, the value of 16 is scaled to 1.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: According to the link you provided, value should be between 0 and 60. It is then scaled. You have input value 100, which is invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an open-source program made on reddit. It can automatically set digital vibrancy when in-game and restore it on desktop.

See [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2bppz6/program_vibrancegui_is_now_open_source/) for NVIDIA (or [here for ATI.](http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2avoky/reminder_to_nvidia_users_that_there_is_a_program/))

You can view the source code at github [here.](https://github.com/juvlarN)

Comment: That's good for whenever I play GO but I wan't this on other games too.